# Nunjucks: How to use relative file paths in html files?

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

If I use `Flask` and `Jinja2`, I can do something like this:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

How do I do something like this with `Nunjucks` and `ExpressJS` ?
Or lets say what is the standard approach in `Nunjucks` to tell the index.html which folders it should use to look for css, js & img files?

Answer (score 3):

In your main file, declare the folder to serve static files.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Now in your template file, if you refer to

```
<img src='/logo.png'>
```

The file `/public/logo.png` will be loaded